# Right way to compare to NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, iphone, nsmutabledictionary

How to compare Two complex `NSMutableDictionary` are same or different

**Dictionary 1**

```
{
    "name": "Hayagreeva", //String
    "age": 3,  //Number
    "subjects": {  //Array
        "rhymes": {   //Dictionary 1
            "test1": 10,
            "test2": 20,
            "test3": 30
        },
        "games": {  //Dictionary 2
            "test1": 40,
            "test2": 50,
            "test3": 60
        },
        "crayoning": { //Dictionary 3
            "test1": 70,
            "test2": 80,
            "test3": 90
        }
    },
    "date": "2008-02-16T10:06:00Z"  //Date
}
```

**Dictionary 2**

```
   {
    "name": "Namechange", //String
    "age": 3,  //Number
    "subjects": {  //Array
        "rhymes": {   //Dictionary 1
            "test1": 10,
            "test2": 20,
            "test3": 30
        },
        "games": {  //Dictionary 2
            "test1": 40,
            "test2": 50,
            "test3": 60
        },
        "crayoning": { //Dictionary 3
            "test1": 70,
            "test2": 80,
            "test3": 90
        }
    },
    "date": "2008-02-16T10:06:00Z"  //Date
}
```

**I used this one but not working**

```
 if ([[NSDictionary1 description] isEqualToString:[NSDictionary2 description]])

        {

        NSLog(@"The two dictionaries are equal.");
        }
        else
         {
             NSLog(@"The two dictionaries are differ.");

         }
```

NOTE: below code work for checking simple dictionary structure HOPE IT HELP to explore the answer

```
NSMutableDictionary * dict1 = [NSMutableDictionary
                              dictionaryWithObjects:@[@"Ravi",@"33",@"India",@"India"]
                              forKeys:@[@"name",@"age",@"location",@"country"]];
NSMutableDictionary * dict2 = [NSMutableDictionary
                               dictionaryWithObjects:@[@"32",@"India",@"India",@"Ravi"]

forKeys:@[@"name",@"age",@"location",@"country"]];
if([dict1 isEqualToDictionary:dict2])
{
    NSLog(@" dict 1 and dict 2 are equal");
}
```

Comment: That will work; doing it properly is not trivial however, but this question has been asked many times before, so please search.

Comment: Could you post the code you use to declare the NSDictionary? Just using `[NSDictionary1 isEqual: NSDictionary2]` should be able to solve your purpose.

Comment: what is *"same"* for you? Same instance, same content, same keys, same values?

Comment: its always goes to false case check

Comment: What i trying to do, if (load request from server Response is change or modified)
{
Load data show refresh
}
Else
{
//no need to update

Comment: I have complex Dictionary key value pair containing array key value as well

Comment: Could just the date always be different?

Comment: need to check every element on comparision to be check

Comment: Create model class (or several), map json data to model's properties. In your model class override `isEqual` method to be able to compare your objects.